# broken data texture rendering in newer three version

Tags: typescript, three.js

I have code for rendering a static bitmap in three js.
This code works in v110 but not in v147. I crawled the changelog, but cannot find the difference.

Data I call the method with is a plain array of integer bitmap grey values so:

`data.length === width*height` and `0 < data[i] < 255`

```
renderBitmap(data: Uint8Array, width: number, height: number): void {

    const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 10000);

    const texture = new DataTexture(data, width, height, LuminanceFormat);
    texture.flipY = true;

    const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
    const geometry = new PlaneGeometry(width, height);
    const plane = new Mesh(geometry, material);

    this._dispose(ImageDataIdentifier.BITMAP);
    this.scene.add(plane);

    camera.position.z = width / (2 * Math.tan(MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov / 2))) / camera.aspect;

    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, camera);
  }
```

Comment: After `texture.flipY = true;` add this line `texture.needsUpdate = true;`

Comment: thanks, but sadly didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- As @prisoner849 mentioned in the comments, you have to set the `needsUpdate` to `true` when the `DataTexture` has been created.
- Second, you can't use `THREE.LuminanceFormat` with WebGL 2. If you want a grayscale texture, you have to expand your data to RGBA or use `THREE.RedFormat` and only sample the red channel in the shader. The latter option is probably not suitable for you since you use `MeshBasicMaterial` and not a custom shader.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. I don't mind to use a ShaderMaterial. The MeshBasicMaterial is only used, as it was the easiest one for this task